# Unable to validate login credentials in my Android app

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I am creating a basic login and registration android app. I am stuck at a place wherein I want to validate my user entered credentials with DB and accordingly allow the user to login which is the default flow for such a system. But the problem is my app taken me to the next Activity even if the entries do not match with database.

I am using PHP/MySQL for backend database connectivity.

Reference Files:-
[BackgroundWorker.java](https://pastebin.com/MNRqBUrc)

```
    public class BackgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{

    Context context;
    AlertDialog alertDialog;
    BackgroundWorker (Context ctx) {
        context = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String type = params[0];
        String login_url = "http://yourdomainip/folder1/login.php";
        String register_url = "http://yourdomainip/folder1/register.php";
        if(type.equals("login")) {
            try {
                String full_name = params[1];
                String password = params[2];
                URL url = new URL(login_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("full_name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(full_name,"UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8")+"="+ URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
                String result="";
                String line="";
                while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null) {
                    result += line;
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return result;
            }
            catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        else if(type.equals("registration")) {
            try {
                String full_name = params[1];
                String employee_id = params[2];
                String password = params[3];
                URL url = new URL(register_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("full_name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(full_name,"UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("employee_id","UTF-8")+"="+ URLEncoder.encode(employee_id,"UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8")+"="+ URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
                String result="";
                String line="";
                while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null) {
                    result += line;
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return result;
            }
            catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Login Status");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        alertDialog.setMessage("Result: "+ result);
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values)
    {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
}
```

[MainActivity.java](https://pastebin.com/WrC7RXsM)

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText et1,et2;
    TextView tv_frg_psw;
    Button btn,btn_register;
    String fullname, password;
    String finalResult ;
    String HttpURL = "http://mydomainip/folder1/login.php";
    Cursor cursor;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        et1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.eteid);
        et2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etpsw);
        btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnlogin);
        tv_frg_psw = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_frg_psw);
        btn_register = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_register);

       btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {

               String full_name=et1.getText().toString();
               String password=et2.getText().toString();

               String type = "login";
               BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker(MainActivity.this);
               backgroundWorker.execute(type, full_name, password);

             }
       });

       btn_register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
               Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,RegistrationActivity.class);
               startActivity(i);
           }
       });

    }


public void perform_action(View v)
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ForgotPasswordActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch(id) {
            case R.id.item1:
                Intent adminlogin = new Intent(MainActivity.this,AdminLogin.class);
                startActivity(adminlogin);
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Item 1 Selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }
  }
}
```

I am expecting the user to receive an error message while wrong credentials are entered ,thus trying to prevent the user from entering into next Activity, but it takes to another Activity inspite of wrong credentials being entered.

Edit1:-
These are my PHP files

```
 **db_connect.php :-**

    <?php
$db_name = "ldsandroidapp";
$mysql_username = "root";
$mysql_password = "root@123";
$server_name = "localhost";
$conn =  mysqli_connect($server_name, $mysql_username, $mysql_password, $db_name);
if ($conn) {
    echo "Connection successfull";
}
else {
    echo "Connection unsuccessfull";
}

?>


    **login.php :-**

    <?php
require "db_connect.php";

$user_name = $_POST["full_name"];
$user_pass = $_POST["password"];
$mysql_qry = "select * from register where full_name ='$user_name' and password ='$user_pass'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $mysql_qry);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) 
{
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $name = $row["full_name"];
    $psw = $row["password"];
    echo "success";
}
else 
{
    echo "error";
}




?>


**register.php :-**

<?php
require "db_connect.php";

$user_name = $_POST["full_name"];
$employee_id = $_POST["employee_id"];
$user_pass = $_POST["password"];
$mysql_qry = "insert into register (full_name, employee_id, password) values ('$user_name', '$employee_id', '$user_pass')";

    if(mysqli_query($conn, $mysql_qry))
    {
        echo "done";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "error";
    }


?>
```

Comment: Where is your PHP code? Are you sure your PHP logic is correct?

Comment: @Dharman - Yes my PHP logic is correct as I have tried creating a dummy HTML form to check registration and login which works fine. Still I will attach the corresponding PHP files for reference